# How to upload an image to Twitter by using pic.twitter.com on Android

Tags: android, twitter4j

I use twitter4j library to tweet but i cannot handle how to upload an image without any other service like TwitPic,yFrog etc.

Is twitter4j supports this, or do i have to use other services?

Comment: You have to use the media extension of Twitter4J and register for a key with TwitPic.

Comment: But  i don't want to use TwitPic. I want my image's link like: pic.twitter.com/dasdas

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to modify the twitter4j code slightly.

There is an explanation here:
http://sholtz9421.wordpress.com/2011/10/29/using-update_with_media-with-twitter4j/